# Push ListView when keyboard pop ups instead of custom Toolbar

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

[image]

From the above image it is clear that what I'm facing problem and what I want to achieve. I am using custom toolbar as relative layout and named as customToolbar and contents like

```
<RelativeLayout
layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
layout_width="match_parent">

<SomeViews
...
...
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have another layout

```
    <FrameLayout
    height=match_parent
    width=match_parent
    />
     <inclue layout="@layout/customToolbar"/>

     <ListView
      layout_width="match_parent"
      layout_height="wrap_content"
      ........
    ......../>


<RelativeLayout
height="wrap_content"
width="match_parent"/>
<EditText
..../>
</FrameLayout>
```

So this is the rough code how i did wrote in my app. I want  to achieve like  figure 3 in above image. how does all the chat apps like Messenger, Viber, whats app does? They just push listView up when keyboard pop ups.. That is what I want to achieve.. Thanks Any help  would be appreciated.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel no doesn't Work.

Comment: put in manifest file in related activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>`

Comment: @JaydeepPatel No change.. Doesn't work!!

Comment: you have to set customView inside toolbar method.

Comment: @JaydeepPatel of course I implemented customView in a toolbar.  Will you please  explain me? I have posted above how I implemented my code and what are the ViewGroups I have used. Please take a look. May be if  i have used default android toolbar I won't get the problem but I need to use this. Please help me out!!

Comment: use the regular `actionbar` and use method to set `customview`

Comment: I can't use default  actionbar because I had used custom view as a toolbar.